# Getting linker error in VC++11 when linking with python27.lib

Tags: python, visual-c++, python-2.7

I'm porting a project from VC10 to VC11, and I'm getting the following errors when linking the component which contains the `initXxx` function called by Python when the DLL is loaded:

```
 1>PyCAL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString referenced in function __catch$_initPyCAL$0
 1>PyCAL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Occurred referenced in function __catch$_initPyCAL$1
```

The funny thing is that there was no problem in VC10, although in both cases, `dumpbin /exports` on `python27.lib` shows only `_PyErr_SetString`, but `dumpbin /symbols` on the object file shows `__imp__PyErr_SetString`.  (I've tried both with and without SAFESEH, as that has caused problems in the past.)

For what it's worth, here's the invocation of the linker from the log file:

```
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"..\..\..\Build\VC11.0\Debug-32bit\PyCAL.pyd" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"..\..\..\Build\VC11.0\Debug-32bit\\PyCAL.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /LARGEADDRESSAWARE /SWAPRUN:NET /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"..\..\..\Build\VC11.0\Debug-32bit\\PyCAL.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH:NO /DLL "..\..\..\Build\VC11.0\Debug-32bit\obj\PyCAL\Loader.obj"
     "..\..\..\Build\VC11.0\Debug-32bit\obj\PyCAL\PyCAL.obj"
```

Does anyone else have any experience with this, and can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're building 32-bit, right?

Comment: Yes.  The version of Python I have was downloaded from the Python 2.7.3 Windows Intaller link at http://www.python.org/download/

Comment: Or maybe not!  I thought I was, but I've got CygWin installed, and when I do `file /c/Python27/python.exe`, it says that the type is an `x86-64` executable.  If I've got a 64 bit Python, and I'm compiling in 32 bits, it's not surprising that I have problems.  I'll verify.